# How to search for a question I viewed for?

Tags: support, search, recent-activity, views

I viewed for a question, but forgot to mark that question as a favorite.

I don't remember:

- the user who asked the question
- the question's title

The only thing I remember is that I viewed the question.

How can I find it again?

Comment: Browser history?

Comment: how if i have clean my browser history ?

Comment: I'm basically saying that you can't. I don't even think the system tracks what you have *viewed*. So if you don't have a record somewhere (such as your browser history), then you're out of luck.

Comment: Browser history works only for them, who uses one system, one user. For those who browse in office's computer, home computers, friends computer. Then The Answer Is ***NO**.

Comment: Recently viewed list would be a handy feature now and again.

Comment: If the _only_ thing you can remember is that you saw a question, why do you want to go back and see it again? There's thousands of others out there you could look at. You don't remember anything about the tags or thing that was discussed?

Comment: You mean you just viewed or **voted on**?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can browse your history.
2. If you don't remember anything, how will you even identify if this was the question you are looking for? If you only forgot the title, not the main content, search for keywords.

Answer (score 0):

If your Server saved opened links record then you can find it again from your server history otherwise if you cleared the History of your system then you can not find it with its url.

Find that like Last time you find it.